# visual studio fatal error LNK1120:

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

just i wanted to make a program using viual stidio 2010
when i do build i have this excaption
i just wrote empty main c++ program (no syntax errors)

what i got is:

```
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe : 
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

code is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

please help me to fix it asap
thanks ,,

Comment: Post your code ... looks like you are missing main

Comment: well i have main as you see..

Comment: maybe some libraries i miss ?? how to fix them?

Answer (score 2):

You created a Win32-Project! Make sure that you choose Console Application in the project wizard.

Comment: iguess the problem cuz library <iostream>
when i use cout<< i have this problem .

Answer (score 0):

Look at your project property. Just go to project settings, linker settings, then system. Check your subsystem setting.You can change subsystem to "not set".It will link based on which entry point function you have defined.